# Как работать с ресурсами проекта?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-faq

Как в *Intellij IDEA 14* работать с ресурсами приложения?

В моём случае это картинки для приложения.

Я создал папку с ресурсами в проекте, а как использовать их — не знаю.

Comment: Как бы вы хотели их использовать?

Comment: Читайте книгу Станислава Давыдова и Алексея Ефимова "Intellij IDEA. Профессиональное программирование на Java."

Comment: Ну в данный момент я ввожу путь до картинки которая находиться в системе а хочу чтобы она бралась из ресурсов проекта

Comment: Не могли бы вы изложить свой вопрос так, чтобы он был понятен и другим. Что за картинка ... какой графический фреймворк вообще ... напишите код, как вы это делаете

Comment: IDEA, Eclipse - не важно. Работать с ресурсами вы будете на языке Java. Про это и читайте. Дам наводку: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/retrievingResources.html.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

вне зависимости от используемого *ide* — **работать** с ресурсами вы будете на языке *java*.

мой вольный перевод справки по ссылке:

### [Retrieving Resources — получение ресурсов](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/retrievingResources.html)

используйте метод `getResource` для чтения ресурсов из *jar-файла*.

к примеру, этот код получает изображения из *jar-файла:

```
// получить текущий classloader
ClassLoader cl = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
// создать изображения
Icon saveIcon  = new ImageIcon(cl.getResource("images/save.gif"));
Icon cutIcon   = new ImageIcon(cl.getResource("images/cut.gif"));
```

в примере подразумевается, что следующие файлы присутствуют в *jar-файле*:

```
images/save.gif
images/cut.gif
```

---

а вот как именно добавить каталоги/файлы с ресурсами в *jar-файл* — зависит от используемого *ide*. подробности должны быть описаны в соответствующей справке.