# Java отправка Email c image

Tags: java, email, изображения

Произвожу отправку email с помощью сервера smtp.gmail.com с использованием javamail.

Письмо без вложения изображения отправляется.

Но когда пытаюсь вложить изображение происходит ошибка

**UPDATE**
Получать ресурс буду в jar.

```
BodyPart attachBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    DataSource source = new FileDataSource("src/prog/icon.png");
    attachBodyPart.setHeader("Content-ID", "<image>");
    attachBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
    attachBodyPart.setFileName("src/prog/icon.png");
    multipart.addBodyPart(attachBodyPart);
    message.setContent(multipart);

    Transport tr = mailSession.getTransport();
    tr.connect("smtp.gmail.com","inau7824@gmail.com", "12345zxcv");
    tr.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
    tr.close();
```

Возникает ошибка при отправке.

```
    Exception in thread "main" javax.mail.MessagingException: IOException while sending message;
  nested exception is:
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: src\prog\icon.png (Не удается найти указанный файл)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1350)
    at prog.Main.main(Main.java:69)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)


at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: src\prog\icon.png (Не удается найти указанный файл)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at javax.activation.FileDataSource.getInputStream(FileDataSource.java:97)
    at javax.activation.DataHandler.writeTo(DataHandler.java:305)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.writeTo(MimeBodyPart.java:1687)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.writeTo(MimeBodyPart.java:991)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart.writeTo(MimeMultipart.java:561)
    at com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed.writeTo(multipart_mixed.java:84)
    at javax.activation.ObjectDataContentHandler.writeTo(DataHandler.java:889)
    at javax.activation.DataHandler.writeTo(DataHandler.java:317)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.writeTo(MimeBodyPart.java:1687)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.writeTo(MimeMessage.java:1906)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1300)
    ... 6 mor
```

Comment: `src\prog\icon.png (Не удается найти указанный файл)` Это стоит вынести в заголовок. Попробуйте прописать абсолютный путь к файлу. Если нельзя, то расскажите почему.

Comment: @defaultlocale ты прав, проблема в пути, но мне необходимо получить путь из проекта

Comment: Тогда нужно рассказать что за проект, как он собирается/запускается, т.к. могут быть нюансы с расположением. Можешь еще погуглить «как использовать ресурсы в Java». Там первым выходит вопрос: [Как работать с ресурсами проекта?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/435751/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0)

Comment: @defaultlocale в jar

Comment: А чем JAR собирается? В частности, попадает ли в JAR папка `src`?

Comment: @defaultlocale да

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задача состоит из двух частей (ПРЕДУПРЕЖДЕНИЕ: непротестированный код).

1. Получить ресурс из JAR файла.

Можно получить поток для чтения файла с помощью [`ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-):

```
ClassLoader cl = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
InputStream imageStream = cl.getResourceAsStream("/src/prog/icon.png");
```

Нужно убедиться, что файл действительно находится по этому пути в самом JAR файле (при сборке Maven по умолчанию исходники переносятся в `classes`, а для ресурсов рекомендуется использовать папку `resources`).

2. Передать его во вложение.

Для этого можно использовать [`ByteArrayDataSource`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/mail/util/ByteArrayDataSource.html) и передать в него поток файла:

```
DataSource source = new ByteArrayDataSource(imageStream, "image/png");
```